# how to get the selected option's label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi-select drop-down and I'm trying to get the complete text from the selected option's label.

```
<select role=select multiple= aria-multiselectable=true class=editable inline-edit-cell ui-widget-content ui-corner-all style=display: none;>
<option value=1 label="UNIVERSAL (aa)"></option>
<option value=2 label="UNIVERSAL (bb)"></option>
<option value=3 label="UNIVERSAL (ccc)"></option>
<option value=4 label="UNIVERSAL Without DT"></option>
</select>

{name:"license", id :"qqq", label:"License", width:"400",editrules: true, edittype:"select",Overflow: "visible",
     editoptions: { 
         dataInit: function (elem) {
             $(elem).multiselect({
                 includeSelectAllOption: true,
                 enableFiltering: true,
                 maxWidth: 400, //'auto',
                 maxHeight: 135,
                 multiselect:true,
                 selectedList: 3,
                 noneSelectedText: "Please select",

                 onChange: function() {
                    var selected = this.$select.val();
                    var selectTxt = $('select option:selected').prop('label');
                    console.log("selectTxt  "+selectTxt );

                    return ;

                 },
              });

           $(elem).multiselect('dataprovider',platdata);

           },
```

Here selectTxt is getting as `UNIVERSAL` which is supposed to be `UNIVERSAL (aa)`.

Comment: Which multi-select plugin are you referring to here? Can you share the link?

Comment: it works https://jsfiddle.net/gtcjdbab/2/. you were missing `"`  (which I was about to mention )before but now I see you updated your question it shoud work.

Comment: @gurvinder372 https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: @bipen I missed it before. Its not working for me

Comment: @Harshitha still not working after the update? it should work. check out the fiddle I posted

Comment: @bipen Nop, Its not working

Comment: @Harshitha, you can check my working snippet below

Comment: @edkeveked Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onchange` function returns the attribute `value` and using that value as an index, I can access the nth option and get the `label`.

```js
$("#select").change(function() {
        var index = $(this).val();
        for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++){
          var label = $("#select option:nth-child("+index[i]+")").attr("label")
          console.log(label);
        }
       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple=multiple id="select">
<option value=1 label="UNIVERSAL (aa)"></option>
<option value=2 label="UNIVERSAL (bb)"></option>
<option value=3 label="UNIVERSAL (ccc)"></option>
<option value=4 label="UNIVERSAL Without DT"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mySelectElement.querySelector(`option[value='${mySelectElement.value}']`).getAttribute("label")
```